# How to delete/move this line of code in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I just have this one line of code:
}

with gray highlight on it. I cannot delete/move it, basically I cannot do anything to it. Please tell me why it is like that and how to delete it?
Thanks

```
for (int iPlay=0; iPlay<1; iPlay++)
     {
      for (int iCount=0;iCount<NonConference.length;iCount++)
      {
          for (int iCount2 = iCount+1; iCount2 < Conference.length; iCount2++)
             {

                 int HomeScore = 0;
                 int OppScore = 0;
                 while (HomeScore==OppScore){
                 HomeScore=RandomNumber.nextInt(100);
                 OppScore=RandomNumber.nextInt(100);
                 }
                   if(HomeScore>OppScore) 
           {Conference[iCount].wins ++;
            NonConference[iCount2].losses++;
           }
           else
           {Conference[iCount].losses ++;
            NonConference[iCount2].wins++;
           }
      }}



    }     //THIS IS IT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!                                     


     //Output

Team1name.setText(Conference[0].team);
Team2name.setText(Conference[1].team);
Team3name.setText(Conference[2].team);


    }
```

Comment: It's a protected block, gotta love those.  Crack open note pad and remove it...

Comment: what if I just leave it there? does it affect the codes after it?

Comment: Yes it will likely have an effect, but without seeing this line, we have no idea *what* effect.

Comment: Yeah, I just tested. It blocks all the codes after it from being executed. But I don't know how to open the project from notepad :(

Comment: If you don't know locate the project copy the text from NB and paste into WordPad. Then remove the annoying line in WordPad, remove the source file from NB, create new from scratch and copy/paste from WordPad.

Comment: There must be more than what your answer contains. The code you have shown will not be "locked" by NetBeans. Usually NetBeans does this only for the code generated by the GUI Editor and you should not modify that anyway. The code in that section will be changed automatically if you customize your Swing components through the GUI editor.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the .java class in notepad and remove the `//GEN - END` code from the file. Now the code should be unprotected in NETBEANS